# Android: Specify String in different Package in Manifest

Tags: android

Is it possible to specify that a @string value belongs to a different package via the Manifest?

i.e. android:text="@string/my_logo_text"

Implicitly specifies the value as belonging to the current package. Is there a way to fully qualify that this string belongs to another package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specify an resource's package you should use as following: `android:text="@package:string/another_text"`

Comment: Hmm.. is this really that simple? no permissions? I can't believe.

Comment: It works well with android system resources. ie: "@android:drawable/ic_media_play".

Comment: according to this: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/911c0c5c5cd50abf, it's possible to load another app's resources from java code using "Context.createPackageContext": http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#createPackageContext(java.lang.String, int)